# Setting a background color in div overflow area

Tags: css, responsive

I'm using the bootstrap tutorial to build a simple responsive page to learn a bit of html and CSS but I'm struggling with one thing.

I have a fluid container, with 3 columns.  Each column is actually 4 grid columns wide.

I have a div in the first column with a height of 100%, background is black, text is white.  Body and children also have 100% height so that the columns fill the page.

This is fine until, say on a mobile in landscape mode, the text is longer than the screen size.

The div fills the screen with the background as I would expect it too - It's 100% of the height of the screen.  But when you scroll into the area that has overflowed, the background is white so you can't see the text.  What I want is for the overflow area to have the background colour from the column.

[image: You can see the columns end once you scroll down]

Edit:  This is my html:

```
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<head>
  <title>Dashboard V2</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
i="0" + i;
}
return i;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;" onload="startTime()">

<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col1" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="time">
            <div id="txt"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to add height : 100% to your divs
it will applied automatically.

Second, to achieve your layout, you may need this way

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        this ful height div
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div>blabla</div>
        <div>down</div>
        <div>boost</div>
        <div>auto</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will display 1 column on xs and sm screens and displays 2 columns starting from md screen. If you want to have 3 columns, change 6 to 4

Comment: ok I removed the height rules from the Row and Col classes and it worked well

Comment: I've edited my post to include my html.  I just removed the heights from everything and it then doesn't adjust the height to fill the page.